# Exclude User's Built Objects From Search

Tags: html, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have an app I'm working on with two models.  Users can create objects with certain traits

I don't want a user to be able to find their own objects.

How do I limit the query?

```
def self.search(search)
where(['primarybreed LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]).where(:user_id != current_user.id)
end
```

current user breaks the above code.  Icluding the sessions helper also breaks the code.

edit: 
controller

```
      @dog = Dog.search(params[:search],current_user.id).sample if params[:search].present?
```

query:

```
 def self.search(search, current_user_id)
   where(['primarybreed LIKE and user_id != ?', "%#{search}%", current_user_id])
 end
```

yield the following error

```
wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: primarybreed LIKE and user_id != ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails 4.x, use this:

```
 def self.search(search, current_user_id)
   where(['primarybreed LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").where.not(user_id: current_user_id])
 end
```

and you can call it as:

```
@dog = Dog.search(params[:search],current_user.id).sample if params[:search].present?
```

Comment: @Peege151 Did you try my answer? Its 7 o'clock of next day :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will solve your problem

```
def self.search(search, current_user_id)
where(['primarybreed LIKE and user_id != ?', "%#{search}%",current_user_id])
end
```

Comment: Where you have defined the method that put current user information inside current_user.

Comment: a sessions helper.  If I include it it breaks though

Comment: Do you know that if the method will inside the controller or helper then you could not use it inside the model.

Comment: send the current user id inside the method search where you have called that method.

Comment: even if I put the current_user method into the model, current_user comes up as nil

Comment: Can you please add that method and session data.

Comment: wrong number of arguments in my conroller       @dog = Dog.search(params[:search]).sample if params[:search].present?

Comment: you need to add the id of current user here like @dog = Dog.search(params[:search],current_user.id).sample if params[:search].present?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in syntax:

```
def self.search(search, current_user_id)
  where(['primarybreed LIKE and user_id != ?', "%#{search}%", current_user_id])
end
```

You pass 2 params but query has 1. Missing "?". Add "?" after LIKE and then check again.

```
def self.search(search, current_user_id)
  where(['primarybreed LIKE ? and user_id != ?', "%#{search}%", current_user_id])
end
```